# PHP Session Management + AWS ElastiCache & DynamoDB

Tags: php, session, memcached, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elasticache

I've been about to implement an AWS remote session management solution and I've been reading others experiences on the Internet.

From my readings I gather that ElastiCache is noticeably faster for PHP Session Management but all sessions could be lost if ElastiCache crashed, ran out of room, AWS maintenance period etc and this would cause all users to logout which is overly desired.

Question: would it be possible to use both ElastiCache and DynamoDB at the same time?

I can see both have a php handler that appears simple to setup but would it be possible (or realistic) to use ElastiCache for sessions but backup to DynamoDB at the same time and then check DynamoDB if a sessions isn't present?

thoughts?

Any opinions on the speed difference between ElastiCache & DynamoDB for PHP Session Management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to combine ElasticCache and DynamoDB. Just use [PHP session handler over Redis](https://web.archive.org/web/20130315202940/http://redis4you.com/articles.php?id=01..). It is very fast, stable and data is backed to disk by default.

Comment: Could you explain why not recommending to use only DynamoDB with his [session handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-dynamodb-session-handler.html) ? Is it much slower than Redis ?

Comment: 1. Price. 2. There was no DynamoDB PHP extension for that. Using `session_set_save_handler` is slower than extension.